# What's a strong attack to use when running away?

Tags: self-defense

I have never done martial arts. I have never done self defence. But I have a long list of things that I WISH you would teach. This is one:

Suppose that you are attacked in the street and you run away. You keep running. But the attacker keeps following. You start running around in circles; you don't know the area well. The attacker knows it better. You're starting to tire; running away isn't working. Also you are not Bear Grylls so doing various acrobatic jumps over fences is more likely to bust your ankle than get distance.

So you have to do something. I would suggest this: partly turning round and extending an elbow backwards into the attacker as he runs behind you, followed by your fist coming over your own elbow with your momentum. That way you have two chances to wallop your chaser: elbow and fist. Sure. This has risk. Your elbow could hit him somewhere hard and break your arm. But there's more risk if you keep running.

If I am an idiot then I'm fine to be an idiot. If I am wrong then truly show me something better. But my question is: when you attack while running as above what should you do? This is why I will never go to a self defence class. Because you don't teach real world self defence. This is real world. A guy was killed in Melbourne, Australia where I live; the CC footage showed him running away from the attacker and he was caught up and fatally hit.

Not trying to sound trollish or provocative. But the whole self defence industry needs to get its act together. The street is not a Dojo.

Comment: This feels more like a rant then a question. "This is why I will never go to a self defence class. Because you don't teach real world self defence." Now, I'm by no means claiming all classes/clubs which purport to teach send defense are effective, but I find it a bit strange you presume *none* of them are whilst simultaneously asking the martial arts community what they would advise tactically in a self defense situation.

Comment: My rants are also passionate questions lol

Comment: Running faster. It attacks the ego of the pursuing person. Seriously, without a balanced base you cannot exert force. And running **is** the best self-defense. You should train it. Or stand your ground. The premise that there are other sensible options is wrong.

Comment: You have misunderstood my OP. I agree taht running is the best defence IF you can get away; the OP deals with the situation when running hasn't created a good outcome. This is exactly why I was unhappy with self defence instruction in the OP; not being open minded to other options. Sometimes you have to do something from a situation that is not ideal - I would argue with my suggested mrthod that with two shots you could get enough force.

Comment: Whoever downvoted it well good one I cannot have a high opinion of an industry that cannot take valid criticism.

Comment: The point is that either you are fast enough or you should realise it in time and get yourself into a good,  defensible position. Defending while running simply isn't a viable option. Self-defense should be about high-chance techniques where a lot of things can go wrong and they still work (this is why all this eye-poking,  pressure points triggering stuff is bad self-defense). There is no such thing while turning away/running/being out of balance by definition. Also,  expect downvotes when posting in bad style, especially when generalising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a matter that many/most martial arts systems focused on self defense tend to ignore, or seem to figure that the answer is common sense. It's like how in my karate days the teacher always said that it's best to run away, yet we never discussed things like parkour, or strategy for escaping, escape paths, or hiding.

On the other hand, classical paramilitary traditions (such as those found in Japan) occasionally have teachings on exactly this. [Tenshin-ryu](https://www.youtube.com/user/tenshinryuhyouho) is a tradition known for it's stylized swordsmanship, though it also includes spear, halberd, and several other disciplines. They have several techniques that reflect exactly this matter - how to counterattack while being pursued. You can see some of it on their YouTube channel, and perhaps extrapolate an answer from that.

In my own practice, which is the nine traditions found in the Bujinkan organization, [one tradition in particular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsdvqbPkJ34) is almost entirely dedicated to this matter in it's fighting techniques.

Many of the techniques can be split into three stages:

1. Being attacked (struck, grabbed, or attacked with a weapon);
2. Doing something to discourage further pursuit;
3. Getting to safety (fleeing and hiding).

The first stage is in regards to angles, positioning, etc. the usual martial artsy stuff with damaging the articulations, percussion, etc.

The second stage is things like throwing something in the pursuers eyes (I once did this with fresh coffee), ear clapping, groin strikes, attacking the legs, etc. A broken nose tends to be disorienting, stunning, and makes the eyes water; making pursuit difficult.

The third stage focuses on flight paths (preferably with knowledge of the area), doubling back, and finding suitable hiding positions.

So all that is to say that there are various systems out there that consider this sort of thing, however, it's a pretty adverse situation that would make it quite difficult to consider what a strong defense would be without looking at specific scenarios. I would be inclined to say that you would want range above all else: thrown objects (sand and things that can scatter would be good), kicks, and weapons, preferably things that can temporarily incapacitate and less likely to kill for legal concerns.